# Extend / Replicate Scala collections syntax to create your own collection?

Tags: scala

I want to build a map however I want to discard all keys with empty values as shown below:

```
@tailrec
  def safeFiltersMap(
                          map: Map[String, String],
                          accumulator: Map[String,String] = Map.empty): Map[String, String] = {
    if(map.isEmpty) return accumulator

    val curr = map.head
    val (key, value) = curr
    safeFiltersMap(
      map.tail,
      if(value.nonEmpty) accumulator + (key->value)
      else accumulator
    )
  }
```

Now this is fine however I need to use it like this:

```
val safeMap = safeFiltersMap(Map("a"->"b","c"->"d"))
```

whereas I want to use it like the way we instantiate a map:

```
val safeMap = safeFiltersMap("a"->"b","c"->"d")
```

What syntax can I follow to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->` syntax isn't a special syntax in Scala. It's actually just a [fancy way](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/3.0.2/scala/Predef$$ArrowAssoc.html) of constructing a 2-tuple. So you can write your own functions that take 2-tuples as well. You don't need to define a new `Map` type. You just need a function that filters the existing one.

```
def safeFiltersMap(args: (String, String)*): Map[String, String] =
    Map(args: _*).filter {
      result => {
        val (_, value) = result
        value.nonEmpty
      }
    }
```

Then call using

```
safeFiltersMap("a"->"b","c"->"d")
```

Comment: The Syntax that you shared is it limited to scala 3 only?
Because I get an error in scala 2.13: Cannot resolve overloaded method filter. Seems like some syntax issue, this works: `def safeFiltersMap(args: (String, String)*): Map[String, String] =
    Map(args: _*).filter {
      result => {
        val (_, value) = result
        value.nonEmpty
      }
    }`

Comment: I would use pattern matching rather than deconstructing the value. `filter { case (_, value) => value.nonEmpty }`

Comment: @ShivamSahil Oops! Looks like I was doing Scala 3 only stuff. Thanks for pointing that out! Sometimes I forget which overload resolution and destructuring rules work in Scala 2. Regardless, looks like someone already fixed the code in my answer.

Comment: Note that the implementation in this answer has some implications on how key collisions are treated:
For example, `safeFiltersMap("1" -> "1", "1" -> "")` will return `Map()` while one might prefer to get `Map("1" -> "1")`.

Comment: @MartinHH that's a valid point hmm, so should it be like eliminate duplicate keys and then go for safeFiltersMap?

Comment: Well: all you'd need to do is change the implementation to filter the `args` before creating the Map: `Map(args.filter { // as above }:_*)`.

Comment: You can simply execute `collect` of map itself, like `.collect{case m@ (_, v) if v.nonEmpty => m}`